# Center Jquery dialog on the parent from inside an iFrame on the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have an iFrame in a page, and I want a Jquery dialog to be centered on the parent, not the iFrame.

I can't find a way to do this though...

This works when I run the iFrame page alone:

```
var LLopt = {
     position: {my: "center center", at: "center center", of: parent.top}
}; 
$("#locationdisplaybox").dialog(LLopt).dialog("open");
```

...but when I try to run it inside the parent, I don't get errors in the console, but it doesn't run (as if there's an unseen error).

I believe this is because of security restrictions of accessing the parent from the iFrame.

If I run the above without " of: window.parent.top" if works fine, but the lower I am in the iFrame page, the lower the dialog appears (not centered).

Does anyone know how I can center this?

To see the problem in action, [please see here](http://videoconferencingbookingsystem.com/results.htm), and click some of the "View Venue Details" links.

Comment: Can you create a simplified version in http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @iKode The iFrame needs to be as wide as the parent pages' width.
You can't open a modal wider than the iframe.

Comment: [Image explanation](http://tinypic.com/r/evb4eq/5)

Comment: Which window (parent/child) initiates the jQuery dialog?... Try to explain in more details please.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe this is because of security restrictions of accessing the parent from the iFrame.

You can't access anything about the parent from within a typical iframe if the pages are not from the same origin. [Here's a good explanation of same origin](http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy).

If your main page and your iframe DO have the same origin, then you can access the parent from the iframe quite easily. Try outputting these values to the console from within your iframe to see what you get:

```
console.log(window.document);     // will give you the document of the iframe
console.log(document);            // same as window.docuent

console.log(parent.document);     // will give you the main/parent document! 
                                  // parent refers to the parent of the current frame
console.log(top.document);        // same as above (if you only have one level of frames)
                                  // top refers to the outermost frame

console.log(window.frameElement); // will give you the frame element itself
```

So, using jQuery, if the element you want is a direct parent of the iframe, you can use...

```
 var $iframeParent = $(window.frameElement).parent();
```

Or if you want some element in the top or parent window and you know what the element's selector is...

```
var $myElement = $(parent.document).find(someselector);
// or
var $myElement = $(top.document).find(someselector);
```

Some other alternatives:

- If you make the iframe width 100% of the parent, then you may get the effect you're looking for.
- Try out the [seamless attribute for iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-seamless).

FWIW - I think what you have looks fine!

Comment: Do you mean the Same-origin policy? it only applies (by default) to pages from different domains.

Comment: @NabilKadimi You're right! I did a little research and modified by answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The same-origin policy is going to stop you from doing anything. I assume you are a developer for whygo.com, and videoconferencingbookingsystem.com belongs to someone else. In this case, you're going to need to ask them to embed some Javascript in their page, like what Google Analytics does: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncTracking

Short of this, you aren't going to be able to be able to get anything from the parent. It is a security issue for the contents of the iframe to access anything from the parent since you can basically act in place of the user of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the height and width, give this a shot:

```
var dlgWidth = 750;
var dlgHeight = 300;

var dlgX = (window.innerWidth - dlgWidth)/2;
var dlgY = (window.innerHeight - dlgHeight)/2;

var LLopt = {position: [dlgX,dlgY], width: dlgWidth, height: dlgHeight};

$("#locationdisplaybox").dialog(LLopt, dlgWidth);
```

You can check this link for the full Dialog definition and methods

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

> String: A string representing the position **within** the viewport. Possible values: "center", "left", "right", "top", "bottom".
>
> Array: An array containing an x, y coordinate pair in pixel offset **from the top left
> corner of** the viewport or the name of a possible string value.